# Зарезервированные символы в Enum

Tags: java

Доброе время суток.
Язык - Java. Нужно создать Enum, содержащий перечисление классов энергопотребления: A++, A+, A, B, C, D, E, F, G.
Проблема в невозможности использования "+" как зарезервированного слова.
Есть предложения, как решить данную проблему?

Comment: @nolik03, вы бы хоть язык указали. А вообще, неужели принципиально использовать значок `+` в названии `Enum`'а? Что мешает заменить его, например, словом `PLUS`?

Comment: 1) укажите язык

2) побуду Кэпом - если нельзя использовать одни символы, используйте другие, те, которые можно. Вместо A+ пишите например APlus

Comment: Поспешил, язык java. Хех, дело в том, что, введя вместо А+ => APLUS, A++ => APLUSPLUS, кроме того, что читабельность никакая, еще и дополнительные парсинги при извлечении значений из файла придется писать.

Comment: >читабельность никакая

очень субъективно. Пор мне так наоборот  в случае с APLUS читабельность куда лучше, чем с A+, коорый можно перепутать с арифметическим выражением (и который по вполне понятным причинам не может быть идентификатором)

>еще и дополнительные парсинги при извлечении значений из файла придется писать

это еще почему? И почему в случае с A+ их писать не пришлось бы?

И еще - добавьте все-таки язык в вопрос и в метки к вопросу

Comment: Был неправ, действительно, парсинги пришлось бы и с + писать.

Comment: @nolik03, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

В Java можно воспользоваться таким приёмом:

```
public enum ConsumptionType {
    A("A"),
    A_PLUS("A+"),
    A_PLUS_PLUS("A++"),
    ...
    G("G");

    private String value;

    private ConsumptionType(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getVlaue() {
        return this.value;
    }

    public static ConsumptionType parse(String value) {
        if (value != null) {
            for (ConsumptionType c : ConsumptionType.values()) {
                if (value.equalsIgnoreCase(c.value)) {
                    return c;
                }
            }
       }
       return null;
    }
}

...

ConsumptionType aPlus = ConsumptionType.parse("A+");
System.out.println(aPlus.getValue());
```

Comment: Благодарю!

Comment: 1) переопределить toString
2) переопределить valueOf
3) ?